# Modal, one script same side

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have this one modal working on my site, but i want one more modal, but how?
Ore maybe a link to working code to help ?

```
<div id="glemsom" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
   <span class="close">&times;</span>
   <h2>Glemt koden?</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
   <p>Modal no 1</p>

 </div>
```

with this script:

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('glemsom');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("glemtkoden");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

How can i add on more modal on same side to the script.

Comment: why not just duplicate the first modal and assign another id ?

Comment: Why are you manually doing this?  With bootstrap this functionality is built in there is no need for the script read the following https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp